# SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have a chat widget (Laravel application) that come form other website. In safari browser it give the cross origin from error. How can solve it ?

I already use

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

but it is not working.

Comment: If you load up dev tools it will likely show you a CORS error (or something else) that will give us more detail about the specific error you're encountering. Can you please share that here?

Comment: This is application i buy.

Comment: Have you tried to use the package https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors ?